# C# LINQ Как получить количество элементов, считая одинаковые подряд как один?

Tags: c#, linq

Например:

> 1,2,3,4,5 - 5 элементов
>
> 1,1,2,3,4,5 - 5 элементов
>
> 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5 - 6 элементов

т.е если рядом, то считать как один, но если одинаковые в разных местах, то нет.

Comment: Обязательно штатными средствами Linq?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал так:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipRepeating<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        bool first = true;
        T prev = default;
        foreach (T item in source)
            if (first || !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(prev, item))
            {
                yield return item;
                first = false;
                prev = item;
            }
    }
}
```

и потом:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5 };
Console.WriteLine(array.SkipRepeating().Count());
```

Можно, конечно, сделать тоже самое в помощью `Where`, но зачем?

Comment: а можно пример с where?

Comment: Нет, потому что лучше так не делать

Comment: у мене что-то типа j.Items.Where(k => k.Value == 1).Count() и мне нужно убрать одинаковые k.Value из Items

Comment: Items - IOrderedEnumerable

Comment: Я вам написал ответ, чем он вас не устраивает? Если последовательность уже отсортирована по этому полю, то одинаковые значения могут стоять только рядом.

Comment: Тоже самое в `Where`: https://ideone.com/Ur11fW

Comment: может я туплю но array.SkipRepeating() выдает ошибку

Comment: SkipRepeating(array)?

Comment: Какую ошибку? Вы написали как у меня дословно? Это метод расширения, он должен быть в отдельном классе, должен быть `this` указан и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение через простой `Where`:

```
int[] array = { 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5 };
var result=array.Where((a,i) =>i-1>=0?a!=array[i-1]:true).Count();
```

Правда, я не понял почему @АндрейNOP не рекомендует так делать... Обращаемся по индексу=> никаких издержек нету.

Comment: Если с массивом (или любым другим IList) – ещё ладно, но автор не сказал, что у него массив

Comment: Ну если в таком контексте, то вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из возможных простых и универсальных решений, это использование метода `Aggregate()`. Пример:

```
int[] array = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 2 };
int? prev = null;

var res = array.Aggregate(0, (total, next) => {
    if (next == prev) return total;
    prev = next;
    return total + 1;
});

Console.WriteLine(res); // 6
```